# SQL Server CTE Query - Rows to Single Delimited String Field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data in SQL Server:

Data creation:

```
-- First we create some test data.
CREATE TABLE E
(
     [Epinum] VARCHAR(9), 
     [RTyp] VARCHAR(120), 
     [Date] DATETIME
);
GO

INSERT INTO E ([Epinum], [RTyp], [Date])
VALUES ('1', '', CONVERT(datetime, '2002-11-26 14:18:00', 20)),
       ('2', '', CONVERT(datetime, '2002-11-24 15:15:00', 20)),
       ('3', '', CONVERT(datetime, '2002-12-17 11:12:00', 20)),
       ('4', '', CONVERT(datetime, '2002-12-09 19:57:00', 20)),
       ('5', '', CONVERT(datetime, '2002-12-11 06:00:00', 20)),
       ('6', '', CONVERT(datetime, '2002-12-19 12:31:00', 20)),
       ('7', '', CONVERT(datetime, '2002-12-15 08:39:00', 20)),
       ('8', '', CONVERT(datetime, '2002-12-20 08:39:00', 20)),
       ('9', '', CONVERT(datetime, '2002-12-13 08:39:00', 20)),
       ('10', '', CONVERT(datetime, '2002-12-16 08:39:00', 20)),
       ('11', '', CONVERT(datetime, '2002-12-14 08:39:00', 20));
GO

CREATE TABLE UJ
(
    [Epinum] VARCHAR(9), 
    [RTyp] VARCHAR(3)
);
GO

INSERT INTO UJ ([Epinum], [RTyp])
VALUES ('1', '111'), ('1', '222'), ('1', '333'), ('1', '444'),
       ('2', '111'),
       ('3', '111'), ('3', '222'), ('3', '333'),
       ('4', '111'),
       ('5', '111'), ('5', '222'), ('5', '333'), ('5', '444'), 
       ('5', '555'), ('5', '666'), ('5', '777'), ('5', '888'),
       ('7', '111'),
       ('8', '111'),
       ('9', '111'), ('9', '222');
GO
```

T-SQL query:

```
-- Now build a query that will create the data we want. 
;WITH Tmp AS
(
    SELECT 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Epinum ORDER BY Epinum) AS rownum
    FROM 
        UJ 
) 
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Epinum, 
    (SELECT 
         RTyp + CASE 
                   WHEN t.rownum = (SELECT MAX(rownum) FROM Tmp WHERE Epinum = s.Epinum) 
                      THEN '' 
                      ELSE '|' 
                END 
     FROM Tmp AS t
     WHERE t.Epinum = s.Epinum 
     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('(.)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS Piped 
FROM 
    Tmp AS s;
GO

-- Great. Now we update the E table, joining on Epinum. 
;WITH Tmp AS
(
    SELECT 
        *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Epinum ORDER BY Epinum) AS rownum
    FROM
        UJ 
) 
UPDATE E
SET e.RTyp = q.Piped 
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         Epinum, 
         (SELECT RTyp + CASE 
                           WHEN t.rownum = (SELECT MAX(rownum) FROM Tmp WHERE Epinum = s.Epinum) 
                              THEN '' 
                              ELSE '|' 
                        END 
          FROM Tmp AS t
          WHERE t.Epinum = s.Epinum 
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('(.)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS Piped 
      FROM 
          Tmp AS s) AS q 
INNER JOIN 
    E AS e ON q.Epinum = e.Epinum;
GO
```

This gets all of the RTyp columns for a particular Epinum and then pipe-delimits them and updates RTyp in table E. It works great, but the problem is, table E in production is ~2.3M rows and UJ is ~900k (both having lots more columns) and this query is taking far too long to perform the update.

How can I make this query more efficient?

Comment: Why are you trying to stuff delimited data into a production system in the first place? It violates 1NF. And are you really saying you are trying to make some of these delimited strings with more than 900k entries? That is a recipe for a performance black hole. Not just shoving the data in there but parsing it later.

Comment: "are you really saying you are trying to make some of these delimited strings with more than 900k entries?" No, I am just saying that there are 900k rows. The delimited strings have a maximum size of 120 characters 40 x 3 chars.

Comment: "Why are you trying to stuff delimited data into a production system in the first place? It violates 1NF." I am aware of that, but we have ready this data to conform to a standard - this field requires pipe delimited values. Out of my hands.

Comment: Understand about being handcuffed. Can you post an execution plan? What about the actual table definition and indexes? Without those kinds of details we are guessing.

Comment: It says that it is the "Table Value Function [XML Reader] Cost: 96%", so I suppose the question becomes, can we create the piped string without doing `FOR XML...`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on the latest version of SQL Server you could try [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
SELECT Epinum, STRING_AGG(Rtyp, '|')  delimited
FROM uj
GROUP BY Epinum;
```

Comment: This does not run, care to update? 
Msg 10753, Level 15, State 3, Line 93
The function 'ROW_NUMBER' must have an OVER clause.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: I can't use SQL Server 2017. Sorry, 2016 at best.

Comment: Corrected the query.  Sorry you can't use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE E 
SET e.RTyp = q.Piped 
FROM (
    SELECT Epinum, Piped = STUFF(
        (SELECT '|' + RTyp 
         FROM UJ 
         WHERE Epinum = t.Epinum 
         FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') 
    FROM UJ AS t 
    GROUP BY Epinum) AS q INNER JOIN E AS e 
        ON q.Epinum = e.Epinum;
GO
```